# How to subscribe for an javascript event form Flex 3 action script code?

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, actionscript-3, dom, actionscript

We have that Flex app talking to the server. We need some kind of *FlexEvent.ON_BROWSER_WINDOW_CLOSE* event but, unfortunately Flex does not provide such.

So I've got the advice to catch a javascript "onbeforeunload" event and call the flash client thru the ExternalInterface-registred method.

Is there any way to subscribe for a javascript event without any javascript code?

**Update** I'm want to do that is multiply flash app hosting pages. Certainly we could manage that by external javascript file, but it's unclear still...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compile the js code inject into your SWF file:

```
package
{

import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
import flash.net.SharedObject;


public class CloseTest extends Sprite
{
    private var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("hello");

    public function CloseTest()
    {
        if (ExternalInterface.available)
        {
            ExternalInterface.addCallback("onclose", onClose);
            ExternalInterface.call(this.javascript);
        }

        this.so.data.count ||= 0;

        trace(so.data.count);
    }

    private function onClose ():void
    {
        this.so.data.count++;
        this.so.flush();
        this.so.close();
    }

    private var javascript:XML = <javascript><![CDATA[function ()
    {
        window.onbeforeunload = function ()
        {
            alert("hello");
            document.getElementById("CloseTest").onclose();
        }

    }]]></javascript>;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use ExternalInterface to call Javascript functions defined in the container. See [this](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=19_External_Interface_06.html#126566).

[This](http://gregjessup.com/flex-3-catch-browser-exit-or-close-event-using-javascript-and-externalinterface/) post describes a situation similar to yours. Take a look.

Comment: This is totally we are doing. However it requires browser javascript to be in hosting page.

Comment: If javascript is not enabled, will you still get the event you want? And if it is, why not put in a line or two as well?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there is no way to do what you are looking for without using Javascript and ExternalInterface.